# Visual Studio 2019: Not showing Typescript Intellisence

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, intellisense

In VS 2019, when I hover I get no help:

[image]

However, in Visual Studio Code I get rich help:

[image]

Is there a way to enable more help in Visual Studio 2019 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Visual Studio 2019: Not showing Typescript Intellisence

1.For now, the default Typescript SDK is `3.6`, so if you have early SDK versions like `2.x`, I suggest you install corresponding TypeScript SDK extensions [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=typescript%20intellisense&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=vs2019&sortBy=Relevance). And according to [this document](https://github.com/Microsoft/JSTSdocs/blob/master/articles/troubleshooting/index.md#enable-detailed-language-service-logging):

*If your TypeScript version is less than 3.1, please Disable dedicated syntax process under Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Language Service and restart Visual Studio (from the same command prompt).*

You can follow it if the TS version you use is less than 3.1.

2.Or you can try updating to TS 3.6 which is default in VS2019.

**Note:** Please make sure you're opening the Solution/Project instead of single typescript file.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the Extensions->Manage Extensions and look in the Visual Studio marketplace.
the only alternitve I can think of at the moment is if your project started outside of Visual Studio 2019 you have a missing reference somewhere not allowing for intellisence.
Without more information, all I can give are suggestions to try.